# Putting a function in a loop

Tags: javascript

```js
function collision() {
    if (player.y + player.height + player.velocityY >= coin.y && player.x + player.width >= coin.x && player.x <= coin.x + coin.width) {
        score = +1
    }
}
```

Right now my collision works but only once if my player collides with two points it only adds one which makes sense because if the statement only gets read once. How can I put this function in a loop? I tried with a while loop but it gave me the call stack exceeded.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: You can make an animate method and call requestanimationFrame as a recursive method and any code you want animating will go in that animate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a game loop. In JavaScript, the simple way is using `setInterval`.

> The `setInterval()` method calls a function at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

```js
const FPS = 30; // frames per second
setInterval(collision, 1000 / FPS);
```

[Example game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9CSWMxJx84&t)

[`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)